# How to import my java class into another java class in Xpages java

Tags: java, import, xpages

In my Xpage, I have added to Java classes. One is "AUser" declared in Models package and one is "AUserRepository" declared in a Repository package.

When I try and import AUser into a class in my AUserRepository... the import statement I type in is not working.

import com.Discussion.utils.AUser;

Weird thing is, If I exit out of Notes and load up eclipse standalone, and make the same kind of stuff, the import works fine. Am I missing out some important factor in Xpages?

The problem definitely is the import routing.

Comment: Please, provide more information. Problem seem to be with class path, what is dependent on many factors.

Comment: By convention all packages in Java are lower case. Only class names start upper case.

Comment: I agree with stefan. If you are going to start creating java classes inside Xpages applications now would be a great time to develop a good set of work practices. This would include assigning package names that are unique across your organization based upon a real (or invented) domain name (com.acme.discussion.utils) using lower case and proper-casing all class names based around nouns (User and UserRepository). With a solid naming standard for packages the class names can define the content rather than the location of the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Models.AUser;
import Repository.AUserRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the project build path correct? `Project - Properties - Java build path`. Also, have you tried cleaning the project? `Project  - Clean...`.